# Print the ResultSet values upto a certain number in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, resultset

this question is a bit weird, but I am after it for last couple of days.

I have sent ResultSet object to JSP page to display the records. It is displaying all the records of resultset in JSP using while(rs.next()){}.

My question is : Is there any method that will print the records of resultset from a certain number_of_row to a certain number_of_row?, e.g.  I want to print the records between row-number 3 to 6.

I dont want Java Classes to take the loads like SQL : SELECT * FROM......LIMIT 3,3;

I want JSP to take step to do that e.g. while(rs.next(from 3 to 6)){}
Any help ? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResultSet has method, [absolute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29) which takes the row no.

So you could simply use:

```
rs.absolute(3);
while(rs.next()) {
    if(6 < rs.getRow()) {//get current row no
        break;
    }
    //get data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with result sets in jsps is kind of pre-historic and not recommended. That said, you could use ResultSet.absolute(int position) to move to a specific row and then count your iterations in a loop.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute(int)

Comment: Thanx..As you said "Dealing with result sets in jsps is kind of pre-historic and not recommended" really that.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cont=0;
int min=3;
int max=6;
while (rs.next() && cont < max){
    cont++;
    if (cont>=min){
        //print
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `absolute  method` of ResultSet Interface will help you

```
boolean absolute(int row) throws SQLException
```

As [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29) says

> Moves the cursor to the given row number in this ResultSet object.
>
> If the row number is positive, the cursor moves to the given row
>   number with respect to the beginning of the result set. The first row
>   is row 1, the second is row 2, and so on.
>
> If the given row number is negative, the cursor moves to an absolute
>   row position with respect to the end of the result set. For example,
>   calling the method absolute(-1) positions the cursor on the last row;
>   calling the method absolute(-2) moves the cursor to the next-to-last
>   row, and so on.
>
> If the row number specified is zero, the cursor is moved to before the
>   first row.
>
> An attempt to position the cursor beyond the first/last row in the
>   result set leaves the cursor before the first row or after the last
>   row.
>
> Note: Calling absolute(1) is the same as calling first(). Calling
>   absolute(-1) is the same as calling last().

Move the cursor  to any particular row and read upto wherever you want , you can use [getRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29) to know the particular Row the ResultSet cursor is pointing to

Comment: But I tried rs.absolute(0), it is showing error. >0 is no problem

Comment: As said in documentation `If the row number specified is zero, the cursor is moved to before the first row.` So if you are setting it to 0 then first you need to call next() method to get the actual row